# Getting ERROR: loading failed for 'i386' while installing package in R?

Tags: r

complete output

Downloading GitHub repo isaactpetersen/ffanalytics@master from URL https://api.github.com/repos/isaactpetersen/ffanalytics/zipball/master Installing ffanalytics "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-35~1.0/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet CMD \ INSTALL \ "C:/Users/Henry/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp6DIfQY/devtools1640625c7659/isaactpetersen-ffanalytics-2078a5e" \ --library="C:/Users/Henry/Documents/R/win-library/3.4" --install-tests

```
installing source package 'ffanalytics' ... ** R ** data * moving datasets to lazyload DB ** inst ** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading ** help * installing help indices converting help for package 'ffanalytics' finding HTML links ... done Constants html
Run_Scrape html
analystOptions html
analystPositions html
analysts html
avgValue html
calcStdDev html
calculatePoints html
calculateRisk html
calculateVor html
finding level-2 HTML links ... done
```

Rd warning: C:/Users/Henry/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp6DIfQY/devtools1640625c7659/isaactpetersen-ffanalytics-2078a5e/man/calculateVor.Rd:19: missing link 'vorBaseline' Rd warning: C:/Users/Henry/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp6DIfQY/devtools1640625c7659/isaactpetersen-ffanalytics-2078a5e/man/calculateVor.Rd:19: missing link 'vorAdjustment' Rd warning: C:/Users/Henry/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp6DIfQY/devtools1640625c7659/isaactpetersen-ffanalytics-2078a5e/man/calculateVor.Rd:14: missing link 'vorBaseline' Rd warning: C:/Users/Henry/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp6DIfQY/devtools1640625c7659/isaactpetersen-ffanalytics-2078a5e/man/calculateVor.Rd:15: missing link

```
'vorAdjustment' clusterTier html
confidenceInterval html
createObject html
dataGadget html
dataPeriod-class html
dataResult-class html
dropoffValue html
ffa.scoreThreshold html
ffa.tierGroups html
ffa.vorAdjustment html
ffa.vorBaseline html
ffanalytics html
firstLast html
getAAVdata html
getADPdata html
getCBSValues html
getESPNValues html
getFFCValues html
getMFLValues html
getMeltedData html
getNFLValues html
getPlayerData html
getPlayerName html
getProjections html
getRanks html
getUrls html
getYahooValues html
mflPlayers html
nflPlayerData html
periodType-dataPeriod-method html
projectPoints html
readUrl html
redistributeValues html
replaceMissingData html
retrieveData html
runScrape html
Rd warning: C:/Users/Henry/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp6DIfQY/devtools1640625c7659/isaactpetersen-ffanalytics-2078a5e/man/runScrape.Rd:26: missing link 'dataResults' scoringRules html
setTier html
siteTables html
siteUrls html
sites html
sourceAnalyst-class html
sourceSite-class html
sourceTable-class html
tableColumns html
tableRowRemove html
```

** building package indices ** testing if installed package can be loaded *** arch - i386

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way. Please contact the application's support team for more information.
This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way. Please contact the application's support team for more information. *** arch - x64 ERROR: loading failed for 'i386' * removing 'C:/Users/Henry/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/ffanalytics' In R CMD INSTALL

Not sure why I get this. Tried installing on my brothers laptop and had no issues. Am using R 3.5.0 but got same error with 3.4.3

Comment: The "*terminate it in an unusual way*" could be due to several things. Do you have Rtools installed and visible to R (i.e., `Sys.which(c('make','gcc'))` returns two meaningful paths)? Can you install other packages?

Comment: I don't see [`indices`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/indices/index.html) on CRAN, how are you attempting to install it?

Comment: my apologies I should have been more specific. The package im trying to install is 'ffanalytics' and am using devtools::install_github. I will post the complete install output in an answer below and post the output of sys.which() below this comment.

Comment: output of sys.which() is make  gcc ""   "". appears the perhaps Rtools isn't installed and visible to R

Comment: And yes i can install other packages